# Is it reasonable to have a "back" button in an Android app?

Tags: android, button, android-activity, back

Please give me feed back whether it's good practice to have a back button in activity, or is it just nonsense?  Maybe some android phones don't have back/return key?  Or do all models have them?

[image: the back button is inside any activity that is lunched afterward]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

All android phones will have the back key. Putting a back button is, IMO, ugly and unnecessary; you better use your space with useful stuff. Sometimes your boss will just obligate you to put a Back button, usually because (sadly) most of the android sketchs are based on iPhone's ones... so the only reason why I'd put a back button is to not get fired (well, sometimes it's much better getting fired than becoming a poor programmer).

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524758/are-the-4-android-buttons-standard-ex-back-button-menu-button) for a more exhausting answer

Comment: does the new specifications say that one have to have a back button in the app as android is going to remove the hard back button in the bottom right?? Couldn't find any official doc. But my senior asked the same to me!! What's ur take man!

Comment: Hard back button is being replaced by a soft one... so you still don't need another back button.

Answer (score 3):

Piling on. I recently had a debate about this where we talked about design metaphors for android, iPhone, and windows mobile.  The bottom line where we agreed is that you should follow the design metaphors for the device you are developing on. For android,  the design should not include a back button because users are used to the physical back button. If one is required, the physical button should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I put a `Back` menu item in the option menu.  The option menu in my apps seem to already contains other navigation-like menu items, so its seems reasonable to have a `Back` menu item in there. Having the explicitly labelled `Back` menu item there seems more newbie-friendly and the redundancy seems harmless there unless the option menu has a ton of menu items already.

OTOH, remembering that there *is* an option menu and remembering how to access it can be a challenge for some Android newbies. Yes Dad - I mean you. :-)

Similarly, on an Add/Edit screen, I provide `Save` and `Cancel` buttons, even though the `Back` button could be (and probably often will be) used to `Cancel` button.  Again, having an explicitly labelled `Cancel` button seems more newbie-friendly and harmless. (What were you going to do with that empty space beside the `Save` button anyway?)

Answer (score 1):

All android phones that want to have android market access need to have a menu, back and home button. those are the rules from El Goog. Some models may not have these but I bet that is a small number of devices. 
I'm not sure if anything will change with honeycomb, seeing as Motorola Xoom has none of these buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an app that needs the space to exclude a "back" functionality, such as an "undo" functionality in a drawing app where you want to show the whole screen, then it's a great shortcut, but you better have a button as well.